# upgrade glibc on RHEL4 without breaking anything

Tags: package-management, apt, rhel4, glibc

I have a static version of wkhtmltopdf which requires glibc-2.4

wkhtmltopdf: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by wkhtmltopdf)

I have apt installed with the DAG repos. Other than that the server is pretty stock standard except for Coldfusion MX7.

My question is, is it safe to just `"apt update glibc"`? Will the updated glibc clobber the old one or will they co-exist? Should I `"apt upgrade"` the whole server?

I'm pretty sure everything else (Apache2, Postgres8, etc) will handle the upgrade but Coldfusion concerns me due to its proprietry nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a version [compiled for glibc 2.3](http://sirping.kafit.se/wp/index.php/category/pdf/)

In answer to your question I don't think upgrading glibc is a good idea as it may well break everything that relies on glibc 2.3.

I had similar problems and the above version worked for me.

Obviously you should make your own security assessment before installing software on the recommendation of a forum posting. :)

Comment: a good answer, though I didn't use it in the end. I just used another server.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the files you need for that wkhsomething (find out which ones with ldd /usr/bin/wkhsomething), do the upgrade, and put them back; just don't clobber symlinks in /lib.

Comment: I don't entirely follow your logic here however i've decided to play it safe and run the wkhtmltopdf application as a service on a more up-to-date machine.